# How do you access a previously shaded texture in a Pixel Shader?

Tags: wpf, shader, pixel-shader

In WPF, I want to use a pixel shader to modify a composite image i.e. a new image overlaid on top of a previously shaded image.  The new image comes in as a largely transparent image except where there is data (think mathematical functions - sine wave, etc).  Anyway this process needs to repeat pretty rapidly - compose the currently shaded texture with a new image and then shade the composite image.  The problem is that I don't know how to access the previously shaded texture from within my shader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to add a `Texture2D` variable in your shader, then set that parameter as the texture you need to access before drawing the new one (i'm unsure of that process in WPF). You do something like this:

```
//blahblahblah variables here
Texture2D PreviousTexture;
Sampler PreviousTextureSampler = Sampler2D { Texture = PreviousTexture; };
//blahblahblah code here
```

then you can sample the texture with a `tex2D` call.